# Move file to a different s3Location in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

My usecase is as follows. I want to move a file from a certain s3Location to a different s3Location, using the Java S3 SDK.
For instance, if the file is in `bucket/current`, I want to move it to `bucket/old`.

I currently can download a file as an S3Object, turn that object into a File (java.io, since the S3 Java client for reasons I don't understand does not allow you to upload an S3Object, the very same object you download!) and upload that file. I'm curious if there is a better approach to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There is no direct implementation of a rename or move operation in S3.  Instead, the typical solution is to copy the object to the new location and then delete the original.  You can accomplish this with the [`AmazonS3#copyObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#copyObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest-) and [`AmazonS3#deleteObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#deleteObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest-) methods of the AWS SDK for Java.

This is more efficient than the technique you described in your question of downloading the file locally and then re-uploading it under the new key.  `copyObject` internally makes use of S3 server-side copy provided in the S3 REST API [PUT Object - Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) operation.  The copy is performed on the S3 server side, so you won't have to pay the I/O costs (and real money costs if transiting out of AWS servers) compared to a local file download/upload.

Please be aware that this is much different from the rename operation as provided in a typical local file system, for multiple reasons:

- It is not atomic.  Most local file systems provide an atomic rename operation, which is useful for building safe "commit" or "checkpoint" constructs to publish the fact that a file is done being written and ready for consumption by some other process.
- It is not as fast as a local file system rename.  For typical local file systems, rename is a metadata operation that involves manipulating a small amount of information in inodes.  With the copy/delete technique I described, all of the data must be copied, even if that copy is performed on the server side by S3.
- Your application may be subject to unique edge cases caused by the [Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [moveObject](https://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/StorageService.html#moveObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jets3t.service.model.StorageObject-boolean-) of the StorageService class.

Comment: As said in javadocs provided by your link `This method works by invoking the copyObject(String, String, String, StorageObject, boolean) method to copy the original object, then deletes the original object once the copy has succeeded.`